# How can i set up a iframe API at TS React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

code of my ScormPlayer component
iframe is loading but i cant access it because
SCORMPlayer.tsx:41 Error accessing SCORM API:  DOMException: Failed to read a named property 'API' from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:63196" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at HTMLIFrameElement.checkSCORMAPI (http://localhost:63196/static/js/bundle.js:1056:45)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IkQP.png)

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Button } from "antd";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { server_address } from "./LoginForm";
declare global {
    interface Window {
        API?: any; // You can define a more specific type for your SCORM API
        API_1484_11?: any; // SCORM 2004 API
    }
}
export const SCORMPlayer: React.FC = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const entrypoint = location.state.entrypoint;
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const iframeRef = useRef<HTMLIFrameElement>(null);

    const HandleGoBack = () => {
        navigate('/clientarea');
    };

    const checkSCORMAPI = () => {
        const iframe = iframeRef.current;
        if (!iframe || !iframe.contentWindow) {
            console.error("Iframe or its content window is not available");
            return false;
        }

        try {
            const scormAPI = iframe.contentWindow.API || iframe.contentWindow.API_1484_11;
            if (!scormAPI) {
                console.error("SCORM API not found in the iframe");
                return false;
            }

            // Example: Check if SCORM API has the necessary methods
            if (typeof scormAPI.LMSInitialize === "function" && typeof scormAPI.LMSFinish === "function") {
                console.log("SCORM API is functional");
                return true;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error accessing SCORM API: ", error);
            return false;
        }

        console.error("SCORM API is not functional");
        return false;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (iframeRef.current) {
            iframeRef.current.addEventListener("load", checkSCORMAPI);
        }
        // Cleanup the event listener
        return () => {
            if (iframeRef.current) {
                iframeRef.current.removeEventListener("load", checkSCORMAPI);
            }
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div style={{ height: '100vh', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            <Button onClick={HandleGoBack} type="primary">Go Back</Button>
            <div style={{ flexGrow: 1, position: 'relative' }}>
                <iframe
                    ref={iframeRef}
                    src={server_address + entrypoint}
                    style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', border: 'none' }}
                    title="SCORM Content"
                ></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SCORMPlayer;
```

on django backend i set up CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True and CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

I tried to re set up my backend and fix code on frontend but i am getting this stupid error

Comment: you can't set things cross origin. you'll have to write a postMessage api